# Concatenating fields in field calculator of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate fields in field calculator of QGIS? (e.g. hectares + ' ha')

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [recent QGIS versions (>= 2.6)](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog260/index.html#feature-additional-expressions-types-and-options), + works for string concatenation

```
tostring(hectares) + ' ha'
```

Previously, the only concatenation operator was: ||

```
tostring(hectares) || ' ha'
```

Answer (score 12):

Right-Click on the layer -> Properties -> Labels 
Then you can use the following function "**concat**(string1, string2,... ) :
[image]

I hope it will be usefull.

Comment: You can also concatenate directly with `"field1" || "field2"`.

Comment: With || you can use all kinds of columns. Using concat(), you can only use strings.

Comment: I usually prefer at least a blank as separator: `"field1" || ' ' || "field2"`. Splitting the label in two lines is also possible by defining a line separator like `/n`.

Answer (score 8):

You can also append text or put spaces between using alternate quotations:

```
 "Streetnum" || ' ' || "Streetname"
```

Comment: I suggest the readers use this solution rather than the popular solution to combine two integers. 
to_string("field1") || to_string("field2")

Answer (score 3):

You can use tostring() to concat number fields Ex hectares || ' ha' || tostring(id)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Using the field calculator, the syntax is: FIELDNAME || FIELDNAME

EDIT: This works on string fields or string-integer combinations. With Integers, it will just perform the math and add the fields together.