# Adding attribute columns together QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis

I am in QGIS trying to combine a Zip code and City (separate columns) together and my methods are not working. Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Comment: What is the type of your columns? To concatenate two string you should use || instead of the plus sign.

Comment: Along with @AlexandreNeto statement, you may want to separate these two field values with a space.  For this you will have to use single quotes with a space (or some other deliminator) between the pipe character, e.g. "CITY_1" || ' ' || "zip" OR "CITY_1" || '-' || "zip"

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation using the + operator has only been added in 2.6. For all older versions you have to use || to concatenate strings.

See also [Is there a way to concatenate fields in field calculator of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12062/is-there-a-way-to-concatenate-fields-in-field-calculator-of-qgis)

Comment: ah... that I didn't know. Nice!