# Need to edit info to new column for label and concatenate information which is alphanumeric

Tags: qgis, editing

I need to end up with the following:
Jones, H.L.
A-345

The data is entered into Survey Name (as string). 
Survey Abstract #is entered as "345"

I need to add "A-" to the number, and then concatenate with Survey Name.  Also want them to post centered and on top of one another for the label....

I'm using GIS for the first time....tried to look for help with this and couldn't find a post.

Comment: the topic of concatenation should be covered by http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12062/is-there-a-way-to-concatenate-fields-in-field-calculator-of-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Possibly there is another formatting problem going on.  The text will only post the first item, and then the rest is blank.  Possibly something to do with overposting option. (Forgive me, this is my first time to use GIS software)

Comment: Please add a sketch of what you'd like to accomplish.