# QGIS Label Expressions

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to create a label that will show the following:
MP 23.6
The "23.6" is a double type column in my table, the "MP" is the text I want to add in front of it of the number (milepost).

I am new to QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform an addition between a string and a number. Instead, use the `||` evaluator which will concatenate both into a string like so:

```
'MP' || "Milepost"
```

You could also transform the value of your `Milepost` field to a string in your expression as in [this question/answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12062/is-there-a-way-to-concatenate-fields-in-field-calculator-of-qgis).

Comment: The OP needs a space between MP and the mileage value.